# Runtime error '1004' unable to set the visible property of the worksheet class in Excel 2010 not in 2013

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a piece of VBA that works fine in Office 2013 not in 2010 giving the attached error. Any ideas on how I can tweak it?

```
Sub UpdateDatesPivots_2019()
    Sheets("2019 dates").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").RefreshTable
    Pivot1 = Cells(3, 13)
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).RefreshTable
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotFields("run_date").ClearAllFilters
    For i = 5 To 1462
        Date1 = Cells(i, 23)
        Date2 = Cells(3, 14)
        If Date1 <= Date2 And Date1 <> Empty Then
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotFields("run_date")
                .PivotItems(Date1).Visible = True
            End With
        End If
        If Date1 > Date2 And Date1 <> Empty Then
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotFields("run_date")
                .PivotItems(Date1).Visible = False
            End With
        End If
    Next i
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).RefreshTable
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables(Pivot1).PivotFields("run_date").CurrentPage = "(All)"
End Sub
```

It gives the error at this part

```
.PivotItems(Date1).Visible = True
```

But works fine in 2013? Any tweaks I can do?

I have looked at other forums and added in code to make sure there are items, old cache items are cleared, but nothing seems to fix it on Excel 2010.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2013 or later, but 2010 and prior had real issues with pivot items that are dates. Most reliable solution sadly is to change the formatting of the source data to general, update the pivot table, then use the number value of the date when referring to the item. I assume there's more to the code, as that all looks a bit pointless?

Comment: To add a bit more context. I am looking up all of the possible dates in a range that I work through from top to bottom in the for (Date1) and compare that to Date2 that refers to a cell with the maximum date that I want to select in the pivot.